# 'list' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, struct

I have a problem trying to decode a float from some bytes in hex.

I read bytes from a zmq message and I add to an array, then I use struck unpack to decode them. But I get that error:

```
lengthOfSensor = frameReceived[count + 1]
print(lengthOfSensor) #number of bytes I have to read for that value
vv = [None] * lengthOfSensor  #init array
for cc in range(0, lengthOfSensor):
  print(count+1+cc)
  vv[cc] = frameReceived[count+1+cc]
print("Measurement")
print(struct.unpack('f',vv))
```

count is a counter and works fine because I get the bytes I want. I already imported struct module. If you think you need anything else to find my error, just ask

Fulltraceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptA.py", line 77, in <module>
    parseFrame(message[1])
  File "scriptA.py", line 56, in parseFrame
    print(struct.unpack('f',vv))
TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of your error; we now have to guess where you get your error.

Comment: `struct.unpack()` needs a `bytes` value, but you are passing in a list. That's not going to work. What are you expecting to get from `vv`? `f` requires a `bytes` object containing 4 bytes.

Comment: And how should I do it?

Comment: It is unclear to me what bytes make up the floating point value you wanted to decode.

Comment: I need to convert some bytes from "message" (it is an array) to a float. Sometimes I need to convert 4 bytes, others 3, others 5... I have the length in the previous position of "message". I want to convert to a float to include it into a json as string. So I can convert bytes to string if the string has the value of the float.

Comment: You cannot convert arbitrary length bytes to float values; you can only interpret 4 bytes or 8 bytes as a float value; the standards for binary representation of floating point values do not leave room for variable byte sizes.

Comment: I see, I need to use diferent method for each number of bytes. How about a 4 bytes length?

Comment: Join the list into a bytes value; `bytes(vv)` would work if each element in `vv` is an integer, or `b''.join(vv)` if they are `bytes` values with just one character each.

Comment: I tried with value = struct.unpack('<f', b''.join(vv))[0] and also fails. I get: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, int found

Comment: So `vv` contains integers. Use `bytes(vv)` instead.

Comment: it works. I had to use bytes. Thanks.